# Unexpected behaviour of SolveAlways

Tags: equation-solving, error-tracking

My problem is quite simple and I cannot spot if this is my mistake or some malfunction of mathematica.

I am using

```
$Version
"12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"
```

Here is the code

```
W := 1/2 (D[h1[x, y], x] D[h2[x, y], x] + 
    D[h1[x, y], y] D[h2[x, y], y])
N1 := 1/2 (D[h1[x, y], x]^2 + D[h1[x, y], y]^2) h1[x, y] h2[x, y] - 
  1/2 (D[h1[x, y], x] D[h2[x, y], x] + 
     D[h1[x, y], y] D[h2[x, y], y]) h1[x, y]^2
N2 := 1/2 (D[h2[x, y], x]^2 + D[h2[x, y], y]^2) h1[x, y] h2[x, y] - 
  1/2 (D[h1[x, y], x] D[h2[x, y], x] + 
     D[h1[x, y], y] D[h2[x, y], y]) h2[x, y]^2
lsq := 2 Sqrt[N2/W]
```

I am making an ansatz for the two functions

```
h1[x, y] = a x + b y + e;
h2[x, y] = c x + d y + f;
```

Then I am using

```
sltn = SolveAlways[lsq == 1, {x, y}]
```

which gives me some solutions. However, when I run the command

```
Table[{lsq} /. sltn[[i]], {i, 1, 14}] // TableForm
```

to make sure that `lsq` is indeed one, the results are `Indeterminate` and `ComplexInfinity`

What is happening?

Comment: `lsq` is an ode depending on unknown functions `h1[x,y], h2[x,y]` . You really  want to solve for x,y?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks for pointing that out. there was some code missing as I copied from my notebook. now it should be well formulated as a question.

Comment: Up to the documentation, `SolveAlways` works primarily with linear and polynomial equations.

Comment: @user64494 I know. However, this statement does not exclude all other cases, at least naively. And to be honest if SolveAlways is unable to find solutions, shouldn't it return the input as output rather than giving faulty solutions?

Comment: After correcting your code (`h1[x, y] := a x + b y + e;` and `=` instead of `:=` in `W,N1,N2,lsq`), the command `SolveAlways[lsq^2 == 1, {x, y}]` results in `{{c -> 0, d -> 0}, {c -> 0, d -> 0}, {c -> 0, d -> 0}, {c -> 0, 
  d -> 0}, {c -> 0, d -> 0}, {c -> 0, d -> 0}, {c -> 0, 
  d -> 0}, {c -> 0, d -> 0}, {c -> 0, d -> 0}, {d -> 0, 
  c -> 0}, {d -> 0, c -> 0}, {d -> 0, c -> 0}, {d -> 0, 
  c -> 0}, {d -> 0, c -> 0}, {d -> 0, c -> 0}, {d -> 0, 
  c -> 0}, {b -> -I a, c -> I d}, {b -> I a, c -> -I d}, {b -> 0, 
  a -> 0, e -> 0, c -> 0}, ..., {b -> 0, a -> 0, e -> 0}}`.

Comment: @user64494 the solutions you quoted I also obtained without shifting to set. if you evaluate lsq on thse solutions it is not equal to one. I never stated that Mma does not give solutions in the post. I stated that it does not give the solutions that it is supposed to give

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0: Sorry, don't understand you. I squared `lsq` to obtain a polynomial.

Comment: @user64494 Let me try to explain. You obtained some solutions for h1 and h2. Did you evaluate lsq on the solutions that Mathematica is giving you? If you do so, the result is not equal to one as it should. This is what I meant

Comment: It's easily convertible to a polynomial system, which it probably does with generically valid transformations (squaring, multiplying both sides) that can introduce spurious solutions. Try `ClearAll[h1, h2];
h1[x_, y_] = a x + b y + e;
h2[x_, y_] = c x + d y + f; 
sltn = SolveAlways[lsq == 1 && (lsq^2 // Denominator) != 0, {x, y}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 this suggestion I understand. Thanks. And I also understand the ouput suggesting that there aren't any solutions. Thanks a lot!